# How to add palletracks to a rackSystem using conditional operator?

Tags: anylogic

[image]

In RackSystem block, is it possible to add palletracks based on a condition. For example,

```
ABC == false ? { ST1, ST2, ST3, ST4, ST5, ST6, ST7, ST8, ST9, ST10, ST11, ST12, ST13, ST14, ST15, ST16 } : {}
```

or

```
if(ABC == false) { { ST1, ST2, ST3, ST4, ST5, ST6, ST7, ST8, ST9, ST10, ST11, ST12, ST13, ST14, ST15, ST16 } }
else {}
```

I have tried both method, but not working.

Answer (score 0):

The easier approach is to have 2 RackSystems, each with their respective racks.

Then, apply the conditional choice of which system to use to the agent flow via a `SelectOutput`

If this is too simplistic, you need to start creating your RackSystem via code and the API constructors, but this is a whole different beast

Comment: thanks. The only problem with that is, suppose palletRack1 belongs to both rackSystem and rackSystem1. i want to use rackSystem in a scenario 1, and the rackSystem1 in scenario 2. it will return an error right? is there anyway to get over this challenge?

Comment: pls always open new questions for new issues, SOF does not work like a back-and-forth forum (which is good: this helps future people with similar issues to figure things out much faster)